# Visual studio code - liveserver not working

Tags: html, css, json, visual-studio-code, liveserver

I am very new to this and i have been having problem with VSC. I have tried closing and starting again and even went as far as deleting and redownloading but to no avail.

[This is what happens when i click on open with live server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEd94.png)

[This is what happens when i click on settings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BXaS.png)

Comment: Could you please share your code and an explanation of what you're doing? At present, all we can see is the results, but unless we know what you're doing, we can't help!

Answer (score 1):

This is completely fine, liveserver can be quite confusing at first, especially when something goes wrong.

The page you're seeing when you open the liveserver often appears when you deploy the server in a parent directory that can't find a visual file to render (deploying on a file like `index.js`).

If you're trying to display a HTML file (example) using liveserver, deploy the server whilst on the file you want to view.  If I were able to see your file directory and the file you'd like to view, I'd be able to help you more easily, but this is a general summary.